SQL query: finding percentages and prices
I have two tables:

The first is used to determine the percentage for the supplier according to salesperson, customer, and quantity.
The second is used to determine the price according to customer, article and quantity. customer is not unique in either tables.

I have created a DBFiddle here.
In the fiddle you can see the results of the join on customer, but it is not entirely correct as some rows are not allowed.
For example the 2nd one: if prices.qty is 50+ then the percentage.qty is >20, and therefore only the second percentage, 0.50 is allowed, not the first (0.25).
The table info:
[percentages]



supplier
salesperson
customer
qty
percent




John
Anne
David
0
0.25


John
Anne
David
20
0.50


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25



[prices]



Customer
article
qty
price




David
X
0
50


David
X
50
40


David
Y
0
50


Mary
X
0
50


Mary
Y
0
55



Quantity (qty) is the lower cut-off of a quantity: it gives the minimum nr of sold items to which the percentage (in the 1st table) or the price (in the 2nd table) can be applied. For exampl,e given John, Anne and David as supplier, salesperson and customer, if the nr of sold item is 0-19 then the percentage is 0.25, if sold items are 20 or more then the percentage is 0.50. Similarly for price: given David and X as customer and article, the price is 50 if the nr of sold items is 0 to 49, otherwise if more the price is 40.
These are the expected results:
[Results]



supplier
salesperson
customer
qty
percent
article
qty
price




John
Anne
David
0
0.25
X
0
50


John
Anne
David
20
0.50
X
0
50


John
Anne
David
20
0.50
X
50
40


John
Anne
David
0
0.25
Y
0
50


John
Anne
David
20
0.50
Y
0
50


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25
X
0
50


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25
Y
0
55


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
X
0
50


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
X
50
40


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0,25
Y
0
50



That is, I have all the possible combinations of percentages and prices that make sense. For example, I do not have a row where percentages.qty is 0 and price.qty is 50, if there is a different percentage for a qty higher than 50.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example  For questions regarding sql this typically involves, table structure, example data and queries as TEXT and not as image.  Additionally to providing these informations within the question, you are also welcome to create a runable fiddle of your problem. Finally, please also tag the respective DBMS you are using ...

Here is a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/2SxOdvL5

@BartMcEndree What in the question tells you OP is using MS SQL Server? Besides that, I'm not even sure what OP is actually asking ...

The only way to beat people with the best answer is to do a lot of work based on assumptions. SQL Server is what I know best. Here is a bunch of math that might trigger a better question https://dbfiddle.uk/6NzK8p53

@BartMcEndree No, the correct way would be to ask for clarification, and vote/flag to close as "Needs details or clarity" or needing "Debugging details".

"Questions should include...., and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used"

@BartMcEndree Wasted effort if OP end up using Oracle, and your answer may get a downvote because it won't work for OP

Please read this >15 year old article: bad habits to kick using old style joins

Please include the code of your [mre] in the question itself. Providing a fiddle is great, but questions must be self-contained, so the example code must also be included in the question body.

Your question is improving, but ...(1) The data for the percentages table in your post does not match your fiddle. (2) You have not posted your desired results. (3) You have not clearly stated the purpose of these tables, or the logic that you need to apply to achieve your intended results. Does qty define a range? (4) "You can see the results ... not entirely correct". No we can't see that, because we do not know what the "correct" results are. (5) "For example...only the second percentage, 0.50 is allowed". You haven't clearly defined the rules for what is allowed and what is not.

I modified the percentages so that they match in both the main text and the fiddle. I explained the meaning of qty. I gave an example of the expected results.

Your description is still confusing. However, your expected results omit only one candidate row from a join between the two tables on customer. If the qty values for each of the two tables are converted to quantity ranges, that omitted row seems to be the only row where the ranges do not overlap.
Based on that, I would propose the following logic:

Calculate quantity ranges for each row of both tables. The original qty becomes the lower bound and LEAD(qty) - 1 becomes the upper bound. (We can use a closed interval, since we are dealing with discrete integer values.) If LEAD(qty) - 1 is null (no value found) the upper end of the range is unbounded.
Join these intermediate results on customer.
Further limit the join to overlapping ranges. A standard test for overlapping closed intervals is lower1 <= upper2 AND lower2 <= upper1. To handle null (unbounded) upper range values, we can substitute a large value using ISNULL().

The result would be something like:
WITH PercentagesQtyRange AS (
    SELECT
        supplier, salesperson, customer, qty, [percent],
        qty AS QtyLower,
        LEAD(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY supplier, salesperson, customer ORDER BY qty)
            - 1 AS QtyUpper
    FROM percentages
),
PricesQtyRange AS (
    SELECT
        customer, article, qty, price, qty AS QtyLower,
        LEAD(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY customer, article ORDER BY qty)
            - 1 AS QtyUpper
    FROM prices
)
SELECT *,
    GREATEST(PER.QtyLower, PR.QtyLower) AS OverlapLower,
    LEAST(PER.QtyUpper, PR.QtyUpper) AS OverlapUpper
FROM PercentagesQtyRange PER
JOIN PricesQtyRange PR
    ON PR.customer = PER.customer
    AND PR.QtyLower <= ISNULL(PER.QtyUpper, 999999999)  -- or ISNULL(..., PR.QtyLower)
    AND PER.QtyLower <= ISNULL(PR.QtyUpper, 999999999)  -- or ISNULL(..., PER.QtyLower)
ORDER BY
    PER.customer, PER.supplier, PER.salesperson, PR.article,
    OverlapLower

LEAD() function is a SQL window function. Window functions allow access to and calculations on values from other rows in the results. using OVER(...) to define the scope of the rows that they access without using a GROUP BY. Typically they are aggregation functions like COUNT(), SUM() or MAX(), but may also be any of LEAD(), LAG(), FIRST_VALUE(), and LAST_VALUE()  that are defined specifically as a window function. The OVER(...) clause defines the scope of the rows being accessed. The PARTITION BY specifies the logical grouping of data, and limits the window function to just one group of rows. The ORDER BY defines an ordering within each partition, for those functions (like LEAD()) that depend on order.  An OVER() clause may also contain a ROWS ... or RANGE ... clause to include multiple rows in the window function calculation, but we don't need that for the LEAD() function. Wee only need to access one value on one following row.
The CTE calculated ranges are as follows:



supplier
salesperson
customer
qty
percent
QtyLower
QtyUpper




John
Anne
David
0
0.25
0
19


John
Anne
David
20
0.5
20
null


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
0
null


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25
0
null






customer
article
qty
price
QtyLower
QtyUpper




David
X
0
50
0
49


David
X
50
40
50
null


David
Y
0
50
0
null


Mary
X
0
50
0
null


Mary
Y
0
55
0
null



Final Results:



supplier
salesperson
customer
qty
percent
QtyLower
QtyUpper
customer
article
qty
price
QtyLower
QtyUpper
OverlapLower
OverlapUpper




John
Anne
David
0
0.25
0
19
David
X
0
50
0
49
0
19


John
Anne
David
20
0.5
20
null
David
X
0
50
0
49
20
49


John
Anne
David
20
0.5
20
null
David
X
50
40
50
null
50
null


John
Anne
David
0
0.25
0
19
David
Y
0
50
0
null
0
19


John
Anne
David
20
0.5
20
null
David
Y
0
50
0
null
20
null


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
0
null
David
X
0
50
0
49
0
49


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
0
null
David
X
50
40
50
null
50
null


Paul
Andrew
David
0
0.25
0
null
David
Y
0
50
0
null
0
null


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25
0
null
Mary
X
0
50
0
null
0
null


John
Anne
Mary
0
0.25
0
null
Mary
Y
0
55
0
null
0
null



Omitted row (customer matches, but ranges do not overlap):



supplier
salesperson
customer
qty
percent
QtyLower
QtyUpper
customer
article
qty
price
QtyLower
QtyUpper
OverlapLower
OverlapUpper




John
Anne
David
0
0.25
0
19
David
X
50
40
50
null
50
19



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
The overlap range calculations in the result are for information only, but they do make use of the LEAST() and GREATEST() functions introduced in SQL Server 2022. For earlier SQL Server versions, you can use an IIF() equivalent together with COALESCE() to handle null upper bound values.
    IIF(PER.QtyLower > PR.QtyLower, PER.QtyLower, PR.QtyLower) AS OverlapLower,
    COALESCE(IIF(PER.QtyUpper < PR.QtyUpper, PER.QtyUpper, PR.QtyUpper), PER.QtyUpper, PR.QtyUpper) AS OverlapUpper

See this db<>fiddle.

Dear TN, this is an outstanding answer and probably exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Still, I am not familiar with what seems to be Transact SQL and I do not understand how you calculate LEAD(qty). Also, in the fiddle at the end I can see the omitted row but not the results..

Glad to hear this helped. The first query in the fiddle shows the intended results. The last one was just present to illustrate what candidate joined rows (having the same customer) were omitted. I've updated the fiddles with comments. I've also added a explanation of LEAD() to the answer above.
